# importing shapefile to geopandas using read_file(); can't print crs or reproject

Tags: projection, shapefile, geopandas

I have a shapefile of historical county boundaries with a valid .prj file. I can open it in ArcGIS and find that the projection is USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic. I can also plot the shapefile after I have read it into geopandas and the projection looks correct.

However, I can't print the name of the coordinate system in my Python IDE.

If you read in the built in data from geopandas

`world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))`

and then run

`print(world.crs)`

you get

`{'init': 'epsg:4326'}`

But if I run

`counties1910 = gpd.read_file('counties1910.shp')`

`print(counties1910.crs)`

all I get is

`{}`

Additionally, I have found that while I can manually run

`counties1910.crs = {'init' :'epsg:102003'}`

without an error, I do get an error if I try to reproject counties1910:

`counties1910 = counties1910.to_crs("EPSG:4326")`

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CRSError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-4aa2873c2f22> in <module>
----> 1 counties1910 = counties1910.to_crs("EPSG:4326")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in to_crs(self, crs, epsg, inplace)
    532         else:
    533             df = self.copy()
--> 534         geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)
    535         df.geometry = geom
    536         df.crs = geom.crs

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py in to_crs(self, crs, epsg)
    408         # skip transformation if the input CRS and output CRS are the exact same
    409         if _PYPROJ_VERSION >= LooseVersion("2.1.2") and pyproj.CRS.from_user_input(
--> 410             self.crs
    411         ).is_exact_same(pyproj.CRS.from_user_input(crs)):
    412             return self

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py in from_user_input(value, **kwargs)
    438         if isinstance(value, CRS):
    439             return value
--> 440         return CRS(value, **kwargs)
    441 
    442     def get_geod(self) -> Optional[Geod]:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py in __init__(self, projparams, **kwargs)
    294             projstring = _prepare_from_string(" ".join((projstring, projkwargs)))
    295 
--> 296         super().__init__(projstring)
    297 
    298     @staticmethod

pyproj/_crs.pyx in pyproj._crs._CRS.__init__()

CRSError: Invalid projection: +init=epsg:102003 +type=crs: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic is ESRI:102003. Because you are using old version of GeoPandas and pyproj, it does not automatically pick it.

Because you are passing it as EPSG:102003, not ESRI, it raises that error.

This should work as intended in GeoPandas 0.7.0 and 0.8.0, which uses `pyproj.CRS` class to store projection information. You will ideally fix it by updating to the latest release (0.8.0).

Alternatively, pass CRS as ESRI (but recommended is an update, if possible).

```py
counties1910.crs = {'esri:102003'}
```